# How to extract values from json request

Tags: json, groovy

Consider this is the sample request..

Now i have to post this.. and once details is added i want to check that correct details only added in the DB. I have extracted the value from DB.

I know that how to extract value from the response... Can any one help me on getting the value from the JSON request... Like i need to extract firstname,lastname,etc.,, can any one help me on this?

Request:

```
POST /MMNRS/1/consumer HTTP/1.1
Host: http://subdomain.example.com
Device-ID: 2b6f0cc904d137be2e1730235f5664094b831186
Client-Type: IPHONE
Client-Version: 1.0
User-Agent: Tap/1.0 (iPhone; U; iOS 4.1; en_gb) 
Accept: application/json
X-Request-ID: 10002
{
    “consumerDetails”:
        {
            “title”:”Mr”,
            “firstName”:”John”,
            “lastName”: “Doe”,
            “dateOfBirth”:”12/05/1956”,
            “email”:”johndoe@gmail.com”,
            “encryptedPassword”:”XXXXYYYYZZZZ”,
            “acceptedTermsAndConditionsFlag”:true,
            “acceptedPromotionsAndOffersFlag” : true
            “versionNumber”: 0
        }
    “twk”: “XXYYZZVVSS”
    “passwordLength”: 7
    “encryptedConfirmPassword”:”XXXXYYYYZZZZ”,
    “confirmPasswordLength”: 7
    “confirmEmail”:”johndoe@gmail.com”,
    “securityQuestionAnswers” : 
        [
            {
                “securityQuestionId”    : 1001,
                “securityAnswer”    : “Rufus the Dog”
                “versionNumber”: 0
            },
            {
                “securityQuestionId”    : 1002,
                “securityAnswer”    : “Beethovan”
                “versionNumber”: 0
            }
        ],
}
```

Comment: You didn't specify which language do you use.

Comment: i am using groovy script

Comment: def groovyUtils=new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context );
def holder = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["PersonalDetails"].testRequest.requestContent


The above two lines pulling complete request.

Now i need to extract firstname only.. this is not working.. 

def p_url = holder.getNodeValue("//ns1:consumerDetails/ns1:firstName:);

Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Groovy (1.8) comes with a built in JSON Parser/Builder

[This link should help you](http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2011/05/groovy-18-introduces-groovy-to-json.html)

Comment: it seems to be we can print those..i need to extract and assign to one variable..

Comment: @user611315 so you just assign them to variables...
if looking at the example you wanted to know the capital


`def capital = states.state[0].capital`

Comment: Consider that i want to extract title for my request. is this correct or not?

import roovy.json.JsonBuilder                                       
import groovy.json.JsonOutput                                     
  
def json = new JsonBuilder()                                      
def title=consumerdetails.consumerdetails[0].title                  
log.info(title)